# How to intercept url loading in cordova

Tags: android, cordova

I'm trying to intercept url loading in a cordova activity, just like I do it in a normal Android application, but I'm having troubles initializing the CordovaWebViewClient!

Here's my code:

```
// In my CordovaActivity's onCreate function:
appView.setWebViewClient(new CordovaWebViewClient( this) {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
          if (loadUrlExternally){
              Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
              Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
              startActivity(intent);
              return true; //the webview will not load the URL
          } else {
              return false; //the webview will handle it
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your logcat message

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution, I wasn't initializing the CordovaWebViewClient right.
Here's how my code look like now:

```
// Load external urls in browser
    appView.setWebViewClient(new CordovaWebViewClient(this, appView) {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            if (!url.contains(AppConfig.BASE_URL)){
                  Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
                  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                  startActivity(intent);
                  return true; //the webview will not load the URL
              } else {
                  return false; //the webview will handle it
              }
        }
    });
```